# Why is not using semicolon is encouraged in standard configuration of eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

My project extends 'standard' rules for javascript in .eslintrc.js file, and according to that Javascript code shouldn't have semicolon at the end of lines. I have never seen something like that. Is it useful to leave it like that? Or am I misunderstanding the whole thing?

"semi" rule from [standard](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard/blob/master/eslintrc.json) eslint rules:

```
"semi": ["error", "never"]
```

Usage from [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi):

```
/*eslint semi: ["error", "never"]*/

var name = "ESLint"

object.method = function() {
    // ...
}

var name = "ESLint"

;(function() {
    // ...
})()
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi

Answer (score 4):

As said in the [standardjs docs](https://standardjs.com/), the point is not to tell it's better or not to use semicolons but simply to settle once and for all a rule

> **I disagree with rule X, can you change it?**
>
> No. The whole point of standard is to save you time by avoiding
>   bikeshedding about code style. There are lots of debates online about
>   tabs vs. spaces, etc. that will never be resolved. These debates just
>   distract from getting stuff done. At the end of the day you have to
>   'just pick something', and that's the whole philosophy of standard --
>   its a bunch of sensible 'just pick something' opinions. Hopefully,
>   users see the value in that over defending their own opinions.
>
> If you really want to configure hundreds of ESLint rules individually,
>   you can always use eslint directly with eslint-config-standard to
>   layer your changes on top. standard-eject can help you migrate from
>   standard to eslint and eslint-config-standard.
>
> Pro tip: Just use standard and move on. There are actual real problems
>   that you could spend your time solving! :P

Discussing about it is opinionated and will induce an endless debate which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

"Standard" in this context refers to a style guide that dictates no semicolons as a default.  It shouldn't be taken as meaning "standard" as in a ECMA standard.

You can see the styleguide here: https://standardjs.com/